# Win32 DLL Not Returning correct data

Tags: c++

I'm very new to C++ programming. I have a 3rd party app that can utilize Win32 DLLs. The test project I'm working on compiles without error, but in use doesn't seem to actually return the expected data.

With the below function Foo, the expectation is that the char array that is passed in will return the same values.

Instead, regardless of the data passed in my 3rd party app only sees the return value: 0

My suspicion is that I am not using the pointer 'char *data_out' correctly.

---

DemoLib.h:

```
#pragma once

#define DLL_EXP extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
DLL_EXP void Foo(char* data_in, char *data_out);
```

DemoLib.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DemoLib.h"
#include <iostream>

DLL_EXP void Foo(char* data_in, char *data_out)
{
    int a_size = sizeof(data_in) / sizeof(char);
    std::string s_a = convertToString(data_in, a_size);

    char strArray[100];
    strcpy_s(strArray, s_a.c_str());

    data_out = strArray;
}

std::string convertToString(char* a, int size)
{
    int i;
    std::string s = "";
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        s = s + a[i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

Exports.def:

```
LIBRARY DemoLib
EXPORTS
   Foo   @1
```

Comment: Check `sizeof(data_in)` and you can't return a pointer to a local array (`strArray`). It will be destroyed when the function returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in your code. First, the line:

```cpp
int a_size = sizeof(data_in) / sizeof(char);
```

will **not** give you the length of the `data_in` string! Rather, it will give you a (fixed) value that is the size of a pointer divided by the size of a char. So, assuming you have a C-style, null-terminated string, use this:

```cpp
int a_size = int(strlen(data_in));
```

Second, your line:

```cpp
data_out = strArray;
```

does **not** copy the string data from `strArray` to `data_out`! Rather, it simply replaces the pointer value (address) that `data_out` holds with the address of the (local) `strArray` array. (However, this will not change the value of any pointer in the calling module.)

What you need to do, here, is actually *copy* the data directly from the `std::string` into the string *pointed to* by the `data_out` argument (assuming it is a big enough buffer).

With these changes in mind, your `Foo` function could look like this:

```cpp
DLL_EXP void Foo(char* data_in, char *data_out)
{
    int a_size = int(strlen(data_in)); // Note: "strlen" returns a "size_t" (unsigned) type
    std::string s_a = convertToString(data_in, a_size);
    strcpy(data_out, s_a.c_str());
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you actually want the function to return a pointer to some local data, then you will: (a) need to declare that local data `static`; and (b) make the corresponding argument a *pointer-to-pointer*:

```cpp
DLL_EXP void Foo(char* data_in, char** data_out)
{
    int a_size = int(strlen(data_in)); // Note: "strlen" returns a "size_t" (unsigned) type
    std::string s_a = convertToString(data_in, a_size);
    static char strArray[100];
    strcpy(strArray, s_a.c_str());
    *data_out = strArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, in your first code block example I get the error: 
Error C2660 'strcpy_s': function does not take 2 arguments

Comment: @jonno Oops! Sorry about that - I didn't check for use of `strcpy_s` rather than just the plain old `strcpy` (now edited). If you really want to use the `strcpy_s` calls, just add the maximum size (of the destination) as a second argument: `100` in the second code block, or whatever your buffer length is, in the first. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32136185/10871073) for a discussion of `strcpy_s`.

Comment: Success! Thank you. I stuck with strcpy_s and added the max size, as using strcpy, generated the compile error:  "This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation..."

Comment: FWIW : using your 2nd code block example, the project compiled, however, when using the DLL with my 3rd party app, regardless of the data_in value, data_out returned: Ðwl

Comment: But remember, in the second case, your *calling* function needs to pass the *address* of a pointer! So: `char* answer;` ... then `Foo(in_data, &answer);`. If you can't change the calling app (3rd-party?) then you will **have** to stick with the first option - as you cannot change the function signature in the already-built app.