# Initialize values in an array of strings c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Hello i'm from Indonesia. and i'm verry beginner on C++   programming. I have some problem when i learn about string on C++  . First i declared array of char and i want to initialize a value separately in different command. After i initialize the value my compiler say "Invalid Argument".

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {

    char Name[5];

    Name = "Luke";

    cout<<"Character 0 :"<<Name[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"Character 1 :"<<Name[1]<<endl;
    cout<<"Character 2 :"<<Name[2]<<endl;
    cout<<"Character 3 :"<<Name[3]<<endl;
    cout<<"Character 4 :"<<Name[4]<<endl;

    return 0;

    }
```

sorry if my english is bad :(

Comment: Name = "Luke";  my compiler say Invalid Argument

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning value to char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915924/assigning-value-to-char-array)

Comment: Because, you can't assign to arrays (you can initialize them, though). Consider reading a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Why not use `std::string`? Or `char name[] = "Luke";`

Comment: thank you for replying me guys

Answer (score 2):

> A character array(including a C string) can not have a new value assigned to it after it is declared.
>
> The C++compiler interprets these assignment statements as attempts to change the address stored in the array name, not as attempts to change the contents of the array.

### However you can use

```
char name[] = "Luke";
```

Answer (score 0):

A `char[]` can't be assigned with a string with the `=` operator, except for on its initialization. That's why     `char Name[5];  Name = "Luke";` is invalid while     `char Name[5] = "Luke";` is.

Assigning strings to `char[]` can be done with `strcpy() / memcpy()`-like functions.

So you have two ways of action (assuming you want to work with `char[]`):

1. `char Name[5] = "Luke";`
2. `char Name[5]; strcpy(Name, "Luke");  /* don't forget to #include <string.h>*/`

Answer (score 0):

Just for sake of education (since the other answers are on-point to answer the question), here's how I would have written your code to do nearly the same thing.

The changes demonstrate:

- used a more appropriate container (a string instead of a char[])
- checked for access overruns
- moved "one unit of work" into its own subroutine

Code was compiled as C++17 with `/usr/bin/clang++ -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat --std=c++1z`:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

void PrintCharAtPos(string const& s, string::size_type pos);

int main() {
  auto Name = string{"Luke"};

  PrintCharAtPos(Name, 0);
  PrintCharAtPos(Name, 1);
  PrintCharAtPos(Name, 2);
  PrintCharAtPos(Name, 3);
  PrintCharAtPos(Name, 4);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void PrintCharAtPos(string const& s, string::size_type pos) {
  if (pos < s.length())
    cout << "Character " << pos << " : " << s[pos] << endl;
  else
    cout << "Character " << pos << " : (out of bounds)" << endl;
}
```