# Dynamic array of fixed length strings

Tags: c++

How do I create a dynamic array of fixed length strings?

I created class **AString** which has pointers to struct **_str** which has fixed-length array **data**.

How to assign values, and what is wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

struct _str {
    char data[20];
};

class AString {
public:
    AString();
    ~AString();
    void Add(_str string);
private:
    _str *str;
    int count;
};

AString::AString() {
    std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl;
    str = nullptr;
    count = 0;
}

AString::~AString() {
    std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
    if (str != nullptr) delete[] str;
}

void AString::Add(_str string) {
    _str *str2 = new _str[count+1];
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
        str2[i] = str[i];
    }
    delete[] str;
    str = str2;
    count++;
    str[count-1] = string;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    AString astring;
    _str str1;
    str1.data="0123456789012345678"; // cannot convert from 'const char[20]' to 'char[20]'
    astring.Add(str1);
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

`str1.data="0123456789012345678";`: cannot convert from 'const char[20]' to 'char[20]'

Want to:
not use `_str str1;`, and use `char str1[20];`

Comment: `AStrring` needs a pointer to an array it can change, but string literals cannot be changed. You have to decide if you want to use the literal's storage, but turn `AString` into an immutable type, or if you want to copy the string literal to a modifiable array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assigning value to char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915924/assigning-value-to-char-array)

Comment: There is an error in your logic. Your destructor `delete[]`s the pointed array but you never `new[]` an array in the first place.

Comment: "dynamic array" in C++ is spelled "`std::vector`".

Comment: Why not using `std::array<char, 20>` ?

Comment: But really, it would be best to just use `std::string` instead of `_str`. And `std::vector` instead of `new[]`.

Comment: It looks like you intend for your `AString` to manage an owning raw pointer. You need to learn about [The rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to avoid problems when you try to use your type. Prefer standard containers like `std::vector` and smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` instead of managing memory manually.

Answer (score 1):

As for me, I used this:

```cpp
   strcpy(str1.data, "0123456789012345678");
```

Here is the main:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    AString astring;
    _str str1;
    //str1.data=const_cast<char>("0123456789012345678"); // cannot convert from 'const char[20]' to 'char[20]'
    strcpy(str1.data, "0123456789012345678");
    astring.Add(str1);

    std::cout << str1.data;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The result is as follows:

```sh
Constructor
0123456789012345678
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would recomend you yo use [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) or [std::array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/?kw=array). But if you forced to use char[], I would recomend you to use [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) instead of operator =, so it would looks like this

```
strncpy(str1.data,"0123456789012345678", 20); // cannot convert from 'const char[20]' to 'char[20]'
```

Answer (score 1):

To copy char* or block of memory, it is better to use `memcpy`!

```
void* memcpy (void* destination, const void* source, size_t length);
```

It copies the values of length bytes starting the location pointed to by source directly to the memory block pointed to by destination. Note that, the underlying type of the objects pointed to by both the source and destination pointers dose not matter.

You can also use `strncpy`.

```
char* strncpy(char* destination, const char* source, size_t length);
```

It works properly for your code but if there is/are some `0` valued bytes, the `strncpy` consider it as `null-termination` and coping continued with '0' i.e. (`pad`) until length is satisfied.

try

```
memcpy(str1.data, "0123456789012345678", 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to arrays - that's just the way it is.
You could use `strncpy` in `main`, or get an assignable array with `std::array<char, 20>`, but if there was a need to do this by hand, I would add constructors (and hide the implementation details) in order to keep things safe:

```
class _str {
  public:
    typedef char base[20];
    _str() { data[0] = 0; }
    _str(const base& in) { strncpy(data, in, 20); }
    const base& get() const { return data; }
 private:
    base data;
};
```

and then you can

```
AString astring;
_str str1 = "01234567890123456789"; // Fine
astring.Add(str1);
std::cout << str1.get();
_str str2 = "012345678901234567890"; // Compilation error
_str str3 = "0"; // Compilation error
```

Comment: hi, I get error: 'base': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration

Comment: If you're using a very old C++ version, such as C++03, you need `typedef char base[20];`.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012. On `base data = {}` I get error: data member initializer is not allowed

Comment: @jsmith I have updated the answer to an older variant.

Comment: Is it possible to create array of strings of arbitrary length? Move "20" to constructor parameters