# When can you use a character array's name to make a valid L-value?

Tags: arrays, pointers, character, lvalue, rvalue

Given a pointer and an array, setting one equal to another fails in one case, and works in another.

```
char *c_ptr = "I'm a char pointer";
char c_arry[] = "I'm a char array";
c_ptr = c_arry;  //This line works.
c_arry = c_ptr;  //This line fails.
```

When the line above fails, it generates this warning: *"error: incompatible types when assigning to type"*.  This error seems disingenuous, and frankly, a little slutty, given that just a line prior, she claimed she was my type.

Trying to understand this issue, I re-read K&R's chapter on pointers and arrays and noticed on page 102 their claim that *"the array name is the address of the zeroth element"*.  If K&R is accurate, substituting in &c_arry[0] should generate the same error, right?  But this line:

```
&c_arry[0] = c_ptr;
```

gives me a new error: *"lvalue required as left operand of assignment".*  Why does this so-called identical value generate a different error?  When GCC and K&R contradict each another, that's when I turn to the experts on stackoverflow.

Reading up a bit on l-values, I've come to the conclusion that this is an L-value vs. R-value issue, and that c_arry can only be an L-value - that is, an assigned value - in two, and only two situations:

- String initialization (i.e. `char c_arry[] = "I'm a char array";` )
- and character assignment (i.e. `c_arry[0] = 'A';` )

Is my conclusion accurate?  Are these the **only** two ways that `c_arry` can ever be assigned?

Or put another way, is there ever an X, for any of the following lines of code, that is ever valid?

```
c_arry     = X;
&c_arry    = X;
&c_arry[0] = X;
*c_arry    = X;
*c_arry[0] = X;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning char array a value in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160233/assigning-char-array-a-value-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that "the array name is the address of the zeroth element" is true most of the time<sup>1</sup> does not mean that you can assign it anything. Although this

```
char str[] = "hello";
```

looks like an assignment, it is in fact initialization; the concept of lvalue does not apply to it.

Moreover, obtaining an address using `&` operator never produces an lvalue, so there is no way to come up with an `X` that does not break your first three examples.

The last two, however, can be assigned, with some minor tweaks:

```
*c_arry = 'x';           // the same as c_arry[0] = 'x'
char *c_arry_of_ptr[2];
...
*c_arry_of_ptr[0] = 'x';
```

---

<sup>1</sup> One notable exception is `sizeof(c_arry)` - here, it's not the same as `sizeof(&c_arry[0])` for arrays of size other than `1`.

Comment: The fact that "the array name is the address of the zeroth element" is not actually a fact. It's rather a lie. (Also, it's probably worth mentioning that arrays *are* lvalues, it's just that they're special.)

Comment: Very helpful and answered so fast!  Thank you.  I'd up-vote you if I could.

Comment: @H2CO3 Why, that's true about the array *name* (K&R choose their words rather carefully).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight because of, for example, `sizeof(arrname)`. The name  doesn't always decay into a pointer (in most cases it does, but not always).

Comment: @H2CO3 You're right, this is worth mentioning as an exception. Thanks!