# Are the values assigned to char array constant by default

Tags: c++, arrays

If I try to assign values to char array. It gives the error.
Error   '=': cannot convert from 'const char [5]' to 'char'.
Why the values assigned to char array are always constant?

```
class Employee
{
public:
    string name;
    char id[100];
    int age;
    long salary;

    Employee()
    {
        name = "NULL";
        id[100]= "NULL";
        age = 0;
        salary = 0;
    };
};
```

here i can't do assignment as "NULL" is considered as const char. while my id is char.
why "NULL" is constant.

while if we individually check then we can change array values.

```
{
    char i[10]="maha";
    i[1]='z';
    cout<<i[0]<<i[1]<<i[2]<<i[3]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You can't assign to arrays, and even if you could, `id[100]` is not an array but one `char`(which doesn't exist because the array only has 100 elements). Read some more about arrays in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160233/assigning-char-array-a-value-in-c

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to fill `maha` in the 100th array index of `id` which is impossible. The array has only 100 indices, you're trying to access an out-of-range index.

Notice that you **can** initialize a char array during **initialization** but not during **assignment** of it.

```
char i[10] = "maha";
```

syntax is an initialization, whereas:

```
char id[100];
id[100] = "maha"; // incorrect
```

is an assignment.

---

### There are two possible ways to solve it:

**Method 1:** Use of `strcpy()` -

```
strcpy(str, "maha"); // copying the string "maha" into 'legend'
```

**Method 2:** Use of pointer and memory allocation -

```
const int SIZE = 100;
char *str = new char[SIZE];

str = "maha"; // it's now modifable lvalue
```

Comment: Can you please explain the point that *str point to first element of array. So, if we are not incrementing it then how whole "maha" is assigned? Like *str adds on first index 'm' then how the next 'a' will be placed on next location

Comment: @LittleStar yes, I also admit that only the first character in the char array is pointed and also it get printed when dereferencing. But the memory for the rest chars 'a' 'h' 'a' were allocated one-after-another.

Answer (score 1):

In your array total size is 100 (Index 0 - 99) and you are trying to set at index 100 which is out of range.

Here array is char means you can set only one character per index. you can not set id[10] = "maha".

You can initialize array by using memset function as below

```
memset(&id[0],0x00,sizeof(id))
```

Use memcpy to update array

```
memcpy(&id[10], "maha", 4)
```

Individual character update

```
id[10] = 'm'
id[11] = 'a'
id[12] = 'h'
id[13] = 'a'
```

Comment: How is that in array [100] i am assigning value to 100th index? Like my second code. In i[10] i have assigned "maha" so m is on 0th index not on 11th.

Comment: How is that in array [100] i am assigning value to 100th index? Like my second code. In i[10] i have assigned "maha" so m is on 0th index not on 11th.

Comment: You can change index by changing value in memcpy(&id[0], "maha", 4) or you can also use strcpy(&id[0], "maha"). When you initialize char array at that point value start from 0th index by default, After that you need to use memcpy or strcpy to update array.